# Can I register multiple tenants within a single Azure Purview account?

Tags: azure-purview

I would like to register multiple tenants on the same purview account. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently in order to scan another tenant's data source, you need to create a separate Azure Purview account in that tenant.